# Does WAMP delete dated databases/tables?

Tags: mysql, server, wamp

I came back to my WAMP install after about 4 months of not using it, turned it on and all is functioning well... But to my amazement, the information in MySQL databases is completely gone. I had two sites running fine off these databases and wouldn't have manually removed them.

I'm just wondering, is there something I've missed with WAMP or does it delete dated data?

Comment: WAMPServer does not update itself and it most definitely does not delete databases on its own. Have you checked the `wampmanager->MySQL->error log` to see if it actaully started mysql properly. Maybe there is a corrupted database, but it will definitely log that fact in the error log

Comment: Yeah I did check that @RiggsFolly I saw the two dates 4 months apart, it didn't look like any errors occurred but I may be wrong. I'll try post the log when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard mechanism to make this happen, no. I can only think that something has either caused the database files to be deleted (although I would have expected errors to be produced if this had happened) or that somebody has been "playing" with it without your knowledge.

Comment: Could wamp possibly have updated in the background? I see quite a bit of 'update' SQL errors on Google... I don't remember updating though. Is there a log I can check somewhere?

Comment: It seems very unlikely - people update their MySQL all the time, and none of them would expect the process to completely delete their databases. There is probably a log item somewhere, but I couldn't tell you where to look I'm afraid.

Comment: I think I lost a bit of work on this. Not something to lose hairs over though luckily, but still kind of abnormal that my databases would just *poof* out of existence.

Comment: It does seem strange - I would advise that you back up your SQL data though - there are tools that come with MySQL to do this, and if you use phpMyAdmin it also provides features for backing up. On my business servers I actually run a cron job (scheduled task) to back up our essential data daily to a networked location so that if anything happens to this server I can quickly re-implement my database - this could be a pain with very large databases though.

Comment: Yeah I understand the importance of backups. Honestly the worst part about losing the information here is that I can't remember where I was 4 months ago. I expected to set it down and then pick it up when I had free time. :(

Comment: I sympathise; it's always difficult to pick up where you left off after some time has gone by, let alone finding your entire database gone when you do!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84625/discussion-between-stej-and-insidesin).